# Turning invite code to url discord rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, discord.py

I set up a command on my bot to pull active invites from servers but cant seem to turn the results into a url.

Ive tried to turn {invites} to {invites.url} and it did'nt seem to work

```py
@commands.is_owner()
    @commands.command()
    async def fi(self, ctx, id: int):
        server = self.bot.get_guild(id)
        invites = await server.invites()
        fetching = await ctx.send("Fetching Invites...")
        await fetching.edit(content=f"All Active Invites Codes: \n {invites}")
        await asyncio.sleep(8)
        await fetching.delete()
        # Fetches invite codes
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Guild.invites`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.GuildChannel.invites) returns a list of [`Invite`s](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Invite), so you need to get the `url` attribute of each `Invite` individually.

```
invites = await server.invites()
invites = [invite.url for invite in invites]
invites_message = "\n".join(invites)
await fetching.edit(content=f"All Active Invites Codes: \n{invites_message}")
```